# Rollercoaster Parallax Scroll Proposal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm creating an animated roller coaster which is linked to the user scrolling the screen horizontally: as the user moves the screen across, a cart moves along the track up/down over loops and climbs. I've so far prototyped some basic examples with the help of [pathAnimator](http://dropthebit.com/592/pathanimator-moving-along-an-svg-path/) combined with [jInvertScroll](http://www.pixxelfactory.net/jInvertScroll/) but the challenge is getting the cart to keep up with the pace of scrolling and stay in view plus have optimal performance. This is the sticking point as in theory the cart needs to speed up if the pace of scrolling is fast enough to make it go out of the viewport range.

This is a rough prototype of the animation here: http://calum.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/

Any suggestions or ideas to make this work better would be much appreciated..

Comment: first of all i dont think that you need this plugins, they are bad for performance, use transform3d which support hardware acceleration, much faster, next you can use position fixed to be sure that cart always in the same place and only switch position of it, and if you wanna add some easing use transitions

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate this but one thing: if the cart is fixed then would it still be possible to define the animation points through a shaped vector or would the entire timeline of the animation need to be manually coded for each and every transform?

Comment: ofc, you can apply all things to el with fixed position that you apply to el with absolute position)

Comment: I've since worked on this and the difficulty I'm now having is measuring where the user has scrolled to accurately by percentage scrolled. With the horizontal parallax it's confusing me how to judge at what point to apply the transform as outputted percentage differs depending on how wide the viewport is.